# Package wrapfig Warning: Stationary wrapfigure forced to float; Collision between wrapping environments

Tags: overleaf

my latex code as follows:

```latex
\vitanew{\vita{3}{l}[h]{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{author-picture.pdf}}
{A. Author}{This is text here. This is text here. This is text here.
This is text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is
text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is text here.
This is text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is
text here. This is text here. This is text here.}}

\vitanew{\vita{3}{l}[h]{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{author-picture.pdf}}
{A. Author}{This is text here. This is text here. This is text here.
This is text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is
text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is text here.
This is text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is
text here. This is text here. This is text here.}}

\vitanew{\vita{3}{l}[h]{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{author-picture.pdf}}
{A. Author}{This is text here. This is text here. This is text here.
This is text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is
text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is text here.
This is text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is
text here. This is text here. This is text here.}}

\vitanew{\vita{3}{l}[h]{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{author-picture.pdf}}
{A. Author}{This is text here. This is text here. This is text here.
This is text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is
text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is text here.
This is text here. This is text here. This is text here. This is
text here. This is text here. This is text here.}}
```

The first three items are displayed as expected, just like my first image.
And the last item is problematic, as in my second image, and gives these two warnings:

Package wrapfig Warning: Collision between wrapping environments on input line 842.
Package wrapfig Warning: Stationary wrapfigure forced to float on input line 842.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, we cannot help you, since we don't know the defintion of the `vitanew` and `vita` macros. Please try to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we are better able to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I found that the ```vitanew``` is a template from a specific journal. This instruction is not an instruction that comes with latex. I will consult the editor to modify it later.